# Why can't I UV-unwrap

Tags: mesh, uv

I've tried multiple times to UV-unwrap objects.  I follow the guidelines from numerous tutorials, but evey time I select Unwrap, nothing happens.

Comment: please add more details, show us the way you tried to unwrap something and maybe add some pictures. it's not possible to help you with the information you provide

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you are not selecting any part of the mesh when you are using the unwarp method, you have to select the desired area so you can unwarp the desire portion on the UvMapping screen.

Also, whe you want to see the unwarped mesh, you have to select the corresponding object, and have an aditional context so you can view it.

good luck buddy, but please, be more specific and add image sthe next time.

Comment: I don't know what else to add, as there's no more detail than that.  It only happens with mesh that I've been working on for a while.  A freshly created primitive unwraps fine.  What did you mean by additional context?

Comment: I'm sorry to be too late, could you please upload the file so i can take a look at it?

Comment: It's not the file itself, because it happens with more than one file.  I suspect it's my computer that can't handle it, even though it's above the minimum system requirements.
Don't worry any further, as I'll sort it out somehow.  Thanks for your willingness to help.